# How to empty the shopping cart when a customer logs in?

Tags: magento, shopping-cart

As the title asks, when a customer logs into their account I would like to clear the shopping cart of any items it contains.

I would like to do this in Magento 1.9. Can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code to delete all shopping cart items of currently logged in single customer:

```
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart'); 
  $quoteItems = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')
                ->getQuote()
                ->getItemsCollection();
foreach( $quoteItems as $item ){
      $cart->removeItem( $item->getId() ); 
 }
$cart->save();
```